# How can we make a Work Item Creator automatically a Follower?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am running Azure DevOps 2019 RC1 with an Inheritance Collection and a new Agile project.

I have a requirement that when a user creates a work item (task/issue), they must automatically be added as a follower of this work item.  How can I achieve this?  I have look in the rules for the work item under process customisation but it doesn't appear to be possible this way.

We are using the tickets to track issues.  Whoever discovers the issue raises the ticket.  The basic requirement is that anyone who raises a ticket should be automatically notified of its progress, even though they are not responsible for the development or testing.

Currently the work around is telling the user that when they create an issue they must click the Follow button, but it is easy for them to forget and then lose their updates.  It seems like a very simple customisation so maybe I'm missing the obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't auto follow things currently, but you can add notification setting that will send automatically emails when work item is updated. To do this, go to **Project Settings > Notifications** page and create new subscription. Select "Work/A work item is changed" and put "Members of ... team by role" in Deliver to selection. Set roles to "Created by" and untick the "Skip initiator".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem would be addressed precisely with the feature requested in the official Azure DevOps' feedback platform here:

**[*479189 - Automatically follow work items I interact with*](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/479189/automatically-follow-work-items-i-interact-with.html)**

*(That page also mentions workarounds, including per-team one answered here, and a per-person alternative. See [this comment](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/717272/view.html). The shortcoming of both is that they don't allow to you to unsubscribe for selected tickets.)*